# Horizontal LinearLayout with three views, middle view should be horizontally centered

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have three items in a horizontal `LinearLayout`: a `TextView`, an `ImageButton` and another `TextView`. All three are vertically centered.

[image]

How can I additionally achieve that the middle `ImageButton` is exactly horizontally centered no matter what the widths of the two `TextViews` are?

That is: I want to have the `ImageButton` at the exact center, the left `TextView` should look right-aligned and the right `TextView` should look left-aligned. All three Views should be vertically centered.

Thank you.

Stefan

Answer (score 2):

Use in LinearLayout:

```
android:weightSum=“3”
```

and at each Layout from your 3 layout use below attribute

```
android:layout_weight=“1”
android:layout_width=“0dp”
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



</LinearLayout>
```

---

Please check Android official documents to check more attribute for LinearLayout:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

you better set weight for them. just play with weight.

if they have a constant weight, they always fill a specific amount of space no matter what.

1-set all views width to match parent.

2- set all weight to 1.

then make sure your image is in center of those text views

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/message" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Childs must have :

1 - layout_width="0dp"

2 - layout_weight="1"

This is the implementation you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="This is a first text" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="This is second text that has a long content than the first one" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use layout weight. Check the below example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout_cancel_x_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text1"
           android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="text1"
           />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="text2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this one...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="This is a first text" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="This is second text" />
</LinearLayout>
```